# Problem with export Azure Sql db and store in a storage account

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-storage-account

i configure an hyperscale db georeplicated but i saw that retention policy is only 7 days.

I found on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/142012/azure-hyperscale-retention-configuration.html

a script that is useful for my scope. I configured it on an Automation account, the Service Principal of automation account is subscription owner and the storage account is configured to be reachable from all network. The strange thing is that via ISE and via runbook script run fine but i see, also after 2 hours, import/export job stuck to 0% and metrics of SQL without do nothing.

Here the script modified for runbook:

```
        #use the Azure Account Automation details to login
     $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
     Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
        
     $myCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'mycredentialsonautomationaccount'
     $userName = $myCredential.UserName
     $securePassword = $myCredential.Password
     $password = $myCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
     $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName,$securePassword)
    
     $DatabaseName ="mydb" 
     $ResourceGroupName="myrg"
     $ServerName="myserver"
        
      # Generate a unique filename for the BACPAC
     $bacpacFilename = $DatabaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"
        
     # Storage account info for the BACPAC
     $BaseStorageUri = "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myblobname/"
     $BacpacUri = $BaseStorageUri + $bacpacFilename
     $StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey"
     $StorageKey = "mykey"
        
     #create the bacpac file and land in the blob storage
     New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password

 #delete bacpac file older than 30 days
  $DaysOld = 30
  $StorageAcctNme = "mystorage"
  $containerName = "myblobname"
  $StorageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext -storageAccountName $StorageAcctNme -StorageAccountKey $StorageKey
  $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $StorageAccountContext
  #cycle through each file by ModifiedDate and delete where gt 30 days from now
  foreach ($blob in $blobs)
     {
         $lastModified = $blob.LastModified
         if ($lastModified -ne $null)
         {
             $blobDays = ([DateTime]::Now - $lastModified.DateTime)  #[DateTime]
    
             if ($blobDays.Days -ge $DaysOld)
             {
                 Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob.Name -Container $containerName -Context $StorageAccountContext;
             }
         }
     }
```

i miss something or i have to setup other thing?

thanks

Comment: so, what's the problem? what's the error message?

Comment: No error message with script execution. Here the output of azure automation:

Answer (score 0):

No error message with script execution. Here the output of azure automation:

```
Environments                                                                                                            
------------                                                                                                            
{[AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureCloud, AzureCloud], [AzureGermanCloud, AzureGermanCloud], [AzureUSGovernme...


ServerName                 : xxxxx
DatabaseName               : xxxxx
ResourceGroupName          : xxxxx
StorageKeyType             : StorageAccessKey
StorageKey                 : 
StorageUri                 : https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx/xxxxxx2106071552.bacpac
AdministratorLogin         : xxxxxxxx
AdministratorLoginPassword : 
AuthenticationType         : None
OperationStatusLink        : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/westeurope/importExportOperationResults/xxxxx?api-version=2020-02-02-preview
Status                     : 
ErrorMessage               : 
NetworkIsolationSettings   : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.ImportExport.Model.NetworkIsolationSettings
```